# reducing repeated uses of jquery selectors

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jquery and I'm finding that I'm writing things like this all the time:

```
if ($("#Menu").zIndex()<200) {
    $("#Menu").zIndex(250)
    return;
}
else
{
    $("#Menu").zIndex(100)
    return;
}
```

I'm thinking that there must be a way to not have to repeat the $("#Menu")-type selector so much.  I see that I could assign $("#Menu") to a variable, and then use that, but blows off the nice ".zIndex" method.  Or I could do something with a function.

What are the best practices for this type of situation?

Comment: What's wrong with assigning it to a variable like you suggest? That sounds reasonable.

Comment: Answered the question. Please provide an accepted answer with the green checkbox next to the voting arrows if you believe this has helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good indicator that you will be using a jQuery element, or something in the DOM, is to preface your variable with a `$`. That way, you know you're manipulating some `HTML` element rather than some standard `var` that is only needed for `javascript` to run.

So, you can use anything you'd like for your `var` name. I just decided to use `$m` to show how much easier it is to write than `$menu` or `$("#menu")`

**Edit:** Another benefit to `caching` it in a variable is your `jQuery` doesn't have to scrub your entire `document` every time you call it. *Thanks for the callout @AdamMerrifield*

## So, something like this is typical practice.

```
var $m = $('#menu');

if($m.zIndex() < 200) {
    $m.zIndex(250);
    return;
} else {
    $m.zIndex(100);
    return;
}
```

Furthermore, you could certainly even shorten the code more with a `ternary operator`.

[Learn More With Interactive Lesson](http://www.codecademy.com/ja/courses/conditionals-in-javascript/4/1)

**Copied From @Hardy's Response:**

```
var $m = $('#menu');
var new_z = $m.zIndex() < 200 ? 250 : 100; 
$m.zIndex(new_z);
```

Comment: Personally I'd use `$menu` for the variable name instead of `$a`.

Comment: lol that is true... but the point isn't that it's as long in text, the point is that the selector is cached and doesn't have to keep being found!

Comment: you are missing the opening `(` at the `if` check.

Comment: Just for my clarity a) I mis-wrote that using the variable "blows off the nice zIndex method"; that must have been a test error, because it's not true; b) the $ preface to the variable is helpful for reading, but not critical to function, and c) ternary operators look like Excel IFF operators, so I finally understand that too, added bonus (expression of gratitude carefully avoided)

Comment: You are absolutely right. You could have just called it `var a` for all `JS` or `jQuery` cares. It's just to help identify, as often times `jQuery` and `javascript` clash for large projects. It is definitely a **best practice**. And your gratitude is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Readability is good practice. You can also do inline statements like:

```
// Read this like "if zIndex is smaller than 200 new_z 
// value comes to 250 else 100"
var new_z = $("#Menu").zIndex() < 200 ? 250 : 100; 

$("#Menu").zIndex(new_z);
```

EDIT: avoid using string type reference to element more than once. Check @Nicholas Hazel answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's short.. :)

Comment: Yes, but in some cases this is really much more simple to read.

Comment: As much as I agree with you, I wouldn't have 8 years ago :-P